# Is there a way to keep track of an object-property's value-history, like memorizing and recalling any of its recent values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, storage, getter-setter, key-value-store

Say I have a method that changes a value based on what the current value is. I will just make it very simple here:

```
  changeValue(){
    if(!this.value){
      this.value = 'value1'
    }
    else if(this.value === 'value1'){
      this.value = 'value2'
    }
    else if(this.value === 'value2'){
      this.value = 'value3'
    }
  },
```

And then I have another method that changes to a fourth value if the current value is either 2 or 3

```
  changeValues(){
    if(this.value === 'value2' || this.value === 'value3'){
      this.value = 'valueX'
    }
  },
```

Now I would like to add a click event that changes the value of valueX back to what it previously was, but I cannot specify it in the code, because the previous value could either be value2 or value3.

Is there a way to look at the variable "history", check what is previously was and then set it back to that?

```
  changeBack(){
    // if last value was value2 change back to value2
    // if last value was value3 then change back to value3
  }
```

Comment: No, there is no built-in feature for this, but you can store the previous value in a different variable `prevValue` or use an array for the whole history.

Comment: Definitely use an array for this - then you can just store the index of the current state and increment/decrement it - assuming the progression is linear, as it appears to be from your description.

Comment: Several ways to store old values but without more context what and @RoryMcCrossan and jabaa said - which of course goes away when you refresh the page

Comment: Though you could use localStorage or cookies or similar if you *really* wanted to persist values even after page reload

Comment: How is this related to vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use an array to keep track of the history of values.**

*Example:*

```js
class YourClass {
  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
    this.valueHistory = [];
  }

  changeValue() {
    if (!this.value) {
      this.value = 'value1';
    } else if (this.value === 'value1') {
      this.value = 'value2';
    } else if (this.value === 'value2') {
      this.value = 'value3';
    }

    // Save the current value to history
    this.valueHistory.push(this.value);
  }

  changeValues() {
    if (this.value === 'value2' || this.value === 'value3') {
      this.value = 'valueX';
    }
  }

  changeBack() {
    // Pop the last value from history and set it as the current value
    if (this.valueHistory.length > 0) {
      this.value = this.valueHistory.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

`valueHistory` is an array that keeps track of the history of values. The changeBack method pops the last value from the history array and sets it as the current value.

Answer (score 0):

```
let valueHistory = [];
function changeValue(newValue) {
    valueHistory.push(this.value);
    this.value = newValue;
}
function changeBack() {
    if (valueHistory.length > 0) {
        this.value = valueHistory.pop();
    }
}
changeValue('hasanraza');
console.log(this.value);
```

Comment: The changeValue function is modified to push the current value to the history array before updating it. The changeBack function checks if there is a previous value in the history and sets it as the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with vue.js, so my answer in vue

You can use vue watchers and make a list and select them by their indexs or object with key: value pairs of all changes.

```
data() {
  return {
    val: '',
    listOfValues: [],
  }
},
watch: {
  val(newVal, oldVal) {
    this.listOfValues.push(newVal)
    // or with if statement if you want to check
    if (...) {
    
    }
  }
},
```

[Vue Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

Answer (score 0):

A generic, non invasive, thus re-usable approach needs to be based on a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap). Such a registry's keys are exclusively references of objects where one for the latter wants to store a value-history for each of the object's entries. Therefore each value of the registry needs to be a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance where a mapping string-based key is the property-name of an object's entry and the value is a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instance. The latter serves as the history-storage for all the recent unique values of an object's certain entry (key-value pair).

Any of an object's property then could be implemented via [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)/[`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) functionality which upon the to be set value does keep track of each new, uniquely set value.

The code then has to be accompanied by two helper functions e.g. `getPreviousOfValueHistory` and `getNextOfValueHistory` where each function upon the passed parameters `target`, `key` and `value` does return for the `target`-object specific `key`-indicated property either the value previously or next to the passed `value` parameter.

In case `value` does not show up in the value-history of the `target`/`key` indicated property, the Symbol-value `Symbol('no history value found')` will be returned.

In case `value` matches either the first or the last unique history value, the value itself gets returned.

Example code ...

```js
const noHistoryValueFound = Symbol('no history value found');

const valueHistoryRegistry = new WeakMap;

const getPreviousOfValueHistory = (target, key, value) => {
  let result = noHistoryValueFound;

  const valueHistory =
    valueHistoryRegistry?.get(target)?.get(key);

  if (valueHistory) {
    const valueList = [...valueHistory];
    let valueIdx = valueList.indexOf(value);

    if (valueIdx >= 0) {

      result = (--valueIdx in valueList)
        ? valueList.at(valueIdx)
        : value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
const getNextOfValueHistory = (target, key, value) => {
  let result = noHistoryValueFound;

  const valueHistory =
    valueHistoryRegistry?.get(target)?.get(key);

  if (valueHistory) {
    const valueList = [...valueHistory];
    let valueIdx = valueList.indexOf(value);

    if (valueIdx >= 0) {

      result = (++valueIdx in valueList)
        ? valueList.at(valueIdx)
        : value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const logUniqueValueHistory = (target, key, value) => {
  if (valueHistoryRegistry.has(target)) {

    const valueRegistry = valueHistoryRegistry.get(target);
    if (valueRegistry.has(key)) {

      const valueHistory = valueRegistry.get(key);
      if (!valueHistory.has(value)) {

        valueHistory
          .add(value);
      }
    } else {
      valueRegistry
        .set(key, new Set([value]));
    }
  } else {
    valueHistoryRegistry
      .set(target, new Map([[key, new Set([value])]]));
  }
}

const getSnapshotOfWritableOwnProperties = (value) => {
  const source = Object(value);

  return Object
    .entries(
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source)
    )
    .concat(
      Object
        .getOwnPropertySymbols(source)
        .map(symbol => [symbol, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, symbol)])
    )
    .filter(([_, descriptor]) =>
      !!descriptor.writable && Object.hasOwn(descriptor, 'value')
    )
    .reduce((snapshot, [key, { value }]) => {

      snapshot[key] = value;
      return snapshot;

    }, {});
}

function withContextuallyBoundUniqueValueHistory(key, value) {
  const { context, state } = this;

  Reflect.defineProperty(context, key, {
    get: () => Reflect.get(state, key),
    set: value => {
      logUniqueValueHistory(context, key, value);

      return Reflect.set(state, key, value);
    },
  });
}

function withOwnUniqueValueHistory() {
  const state = getSnapshotOfWritableOwnProperties(this);

  Object
    .entries(state)
    .concat(
      Object
        .getOwnPropertySymbols(state)
        .map(symbol => [symbol, Reflect.get(state, symbol)])
    )
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {

      withContextuallyBoundUniqueValueHistory
        .call({ context: this, state }, key, value);

      // - force 1st history-value entry
      //   for every instance property.
      this[key] = value;
    });
}

class KeyValueStorageWithUniqueValueHistory {

  constructor(initialState= {}) {
    Object
      .assign(this, Object(initialState));

    withOwnUniqueValueHistory.call(this);
  }
  previousValueOf(/* key, value? */...args) {
    const key = args.at(0);
    const value = ('1' in args) ? args.at(1) : this[key];

    return getPreviousOfValueHistory(this, key, value);
  }
  nextValueOf(/* key, value? */...args) {
    const key = args.at(0);
    const value = ('1' in args) ? args.at(1) : this[key];

    return getNextOfValueHistory(this, key, value);
  }
}
const fooBarSymbol = Symbol('fooBar');

const storage = new KeyValueStorageWithUniqueValueHistory({
  quickBrownFox: 'the',
  [fooBarSymbol]: 'foo',
});

console.log(`const storage = new KeyValueStorageWithUniqueValueHistory({
  quickBrownFox: 'the',
  [fooBarSymbol]: 'foo',
});`);
console.log('storage.quickBrownFox ...', storage.quickBrownFox);
console.log('\n');

console.log("storage.quickBrownFox = 'quick';");
storage.quickBrownFox = 'quick';
console.log('storage.quickBrownFox ...', storage.quickBrownFox);
console.log('\n');

console.log("storage.quickBrownFox = 'brown';");
storage.quickBrownFox = 'brown';
console.log('storage.quickBrownFox ...', storage.quickBrownFox);
console.log('\n');

console.log("storage.quickBrownFox = 'fox';");
storage.quickBrownFox = 'fox';
console.log('storage.quickBrownFox ...', storage.quickBrownFox);
console.log('\n');

console.log("storage.quickBrownFox = 'jumps';");
storage.quickBrownFox = 'jumps';
console.log('storage.quickBrownFox ...', storage.quickBrownFox);

console.log('----- ----- ----- ----- -----');

console.log("storage.quickBrownFox = 'brown';");
storage.quickBrownFox = 'brown';
console.log('storage.quickBrownFox ...', storage.quickBrownFox);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "storage.previousValueOf('quickBrownFox') ...",
  storage.previousValueOf('quickBrownFox'),
);
console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf('quickBrownFox') ...",
  storage.nextValueOf('quickBrownFox'),
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "storage.previousValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'quick') ...",
  storage.previousValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'quick'),
);
console.log(
  "storage.previousValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'jumps') ...",
  storage.previousValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'jumps'),
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'the') ...",
  storage.nextValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'the'),
);
console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'fox') ...",
  storage.nextValueOf('quickBrownFox', 'fox'),
);

console.log('----- ----- ----- ----- -----');

console.log('storage[fooBarSymbol] ...',storage[fooBarSymbol]);

console.log(
  "storage.previousValueOf(fooBarSymbol) ...",
  storage.previousValueOf(fooBarSymbol),
);
console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol) ...",
  storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol),
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol, 'bar') ...",
  String(storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol, 'bar')),
);

console.log('----- ----- ----- ----- -----');

console.log("storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'bar';");
storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'bar';
console.log('storage[fooBarSymbol] ...', storage[fooBarSymbol]);
console.log('\n');

console.log("storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'baz';");
storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'baz';
console.log('storage[fooBarSymbol] ...', storage[fooBarSymbol]);
console.log('\n');

console.log("storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'biz';");
storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'biz';
console.log('storage[fooBarSymbol] ...', storage[fooBarSymbol]);

console.log('----- ----- ----- ----- -----');

console.log("storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'bar';");
storage[fooBarSymbol] = 'bar';
console.log('storage[fooBarSymbol] ...', storage[fooBarSymbol]);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "storage.previousValueOf(fooBarSymbol) ...",
  storage.previousValueOf(fooBarSymbol),
);
console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol) ...",
  storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol),
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "storage.previousValueOf(fooBarSymbol, 'biz') ...",
  storage.previousValueOf(fooBarSymbol, 'biz'),
);
console.log(
  "storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol, 'baz') ...",
  storage.nextValueOf(fooBarSymbol, 'baz'),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Taking everything into account which got provided by the above example code, the OP now could easily implement a generic `changeBack` methods like follows ...

```
setPreviousValueOf(/* key, value? */...args) {
  const key = args.at(0);
  const value = ('1' in args) ? args.at(1) : this[key];

  this[key] = getPreviousOfValueHistory(this, key, value);
}
```

... which then could be used like ...

```
this.setPreviousValueOf('valueX'/*,anyCurrentOrPreviousValueOfProperty_valueX*/);
```

Again, the stack snippet's example code does provide the implementation of `getPreviousOfValueHistory` and an example of its usage.

Comment: @Scandidi ... The OP might have a look at the late provided, above example code and answer which on a generic base solve any of the OP's current and future problems related to any object property's unique value-history.